# Общее количество недель в месяце

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Как определить общее количество (неполные + полные) недель в произвольном месяце? Исходим из того что неделя начинается с понедельника и заканчивается воскресеньем. Другими словами, сколько строк календаря занимает тот или иной месяц.

```
Ноя.2015 - 6 недель (01.11 - Вс, 30.11 - Пн)
Дек.2015 - 5 недель (01.12 - Вт, 31.12 - Чт)
```

Comment: Так что именно вы хотите получить? Количество **неполных** недель в месяце или **общее** количество недель в месяце?

Comment: Общее количество недель (неполные + полные). Действительно, не корректно поставил вопрос. Сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На основании дня недели последнего числа месяца находим число дней прошедших *до* последнего понедельника. Делим это число на 7 и округляем вверх, получаем кол-во недель прошедших *до* последней недели, прибавляем 1.

```
function getWeeks(year, month) // Внимание: Месяцы нумеруются с 0, как принято в JS
 {
  var l=new Date(year, month+1, 0);
  return Math.ceil( (l.getDate()- (l.getDay()?l.getDay():7))/7 )+1;
 }
```

Comment: `Math.ceil((l.getTime() - f.getTime()) / 604800000)`
Как вариант

Comment: Ан нет, ваше новое решение мне нравится больше

Comment: Но почему не `function getWeeks(year, month) { return Math.ceil(new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate() / 7); }`

Comment: День недели надо учитывать. В сентябре и в ноябре по 30 дней, но сентябрь 5 недель, ноябрь - 6, потому что в ноябре 30 число понедельник, чуть чуть вылезло

Comment: да, спасибо, не подумал

Answer (score -1):

Для российской недели (пн-вс):

```
function weeks_in_month(year, month) {
    var weeks = 1;
    var day = -1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= days_in_month; i++) {
        var newday = new Date(year, month, i).getDay();
        if (day == 0 && newday == 1) {
            weeks += 1;
        }
        day = newday;
    }
    return weeks;
}

for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
    console.log(weeks_in_month(2015, i));
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 6
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 6
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 6
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: 5
```

---

Корректный алгоритм без перебора всех дней месяца:

```
function first_monday_in_month(year, month, monday) {
    var day = new Date(year, month, 1);
    while (day.getDay() != monday) {
        day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return day;
}


function weeks_in_month(year, month, week_start_day) {
    var monday = first_monday_in_month(year, month, week_start_day);
    var weeks = monday.getTime() == (new Date(year, month, 1)).getTime() ? 0 : 1;
    while (monday.getMonth() == month) {
        monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 7);
        weeks++;
    }
    return weeks;
}
```

Comment: Очень уж не эффективно проводить итерации по каждому дню месяца

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что в феврале 2015 года было 6 недель?

Comment: @Yaant, Вы правы, нужно корректно вычислить кол-во дней в месяце. Этот способ (`new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()`) я нагуглил, а он не работает. Вот это точно сработает: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881938/javascript-calculate-number-of-days-in-month-for-a-given-year

Comment: @andy.37 new Date(year, month, 0).getDate() отлично работает, только месяц надо на 1 больше брать. потому как 0 февраля - это 31 января

Comment: В вашем коде, переменная `days_in_month` не определена!