# Нумерация недель в квартале sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, redshift

Поделитесь идеями или опытом подсчета номеров недель в каждом квартале. Считаю в Redshift.
Первый номер начинается с первого дня квартала. Второй номер начинается со следующего понедельника. Т.е. первая и последняя недели квартала не всегда семидневные отрезки с понедельника по воскресенье.
Я попробовала считать недели между 1 и последним днем каждого квартала:

```
round((extract('day' from  (date_op - date_trunc('QUARTER',date_op))))/7+1)
```

Этот подход оказался нерабочим. Со второго квартала недели начинают считаться с воскресенья.

Извлечь нумерацию из нумерации недель года тоже нельзя, т.к. считаю в таком случае просто семидневные отрезки:

> DATE_PART(WEEK,date_op))%13 + 1.

По форумам и тут похожих вычислений не нашла.
Буду признательна за любую помощь.

Comment: Думаю что то на основе этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475640/194569 можно сделать

Comment: Что-то похожее пыталась, используя первый способ: количество дней в квартале, но считаю все равно неправильно

Comment: от количества дней считать нельзя. надо делать коррекцию на последний понедельник. т.е. по количеству дней от последнего понедельника до конца периода

Comment: Пока слабо представляю как это сделать. Но за идею спасибо! :)

Comment: А что именно вы хотите посчитать? По дате определить номер недели в квартале?

Comment: Да, именно это я и пытаюсь сейчас определить

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы зря отказались от варианта с номером недели. Как мне кажется вот это может быть рабочим вариантом:

```
SELECT date_part('WEEK', date_op) - date_part('WEEK', date_trunc('QUARTER', date_op)) + 1;
```

Т.е. мы определяем номер недели для текущей даты, а так же определяем номер недели для начала квартала. И находим разницу между ними.

Для сегоднянего числа выдает 11 - это вроде бы правильно, если я правильно понял условие задачи.

Comment: Да, я уже собиралась сюда писать решение) Судя по результату ( и то что не только мне это на ум пришло) --решение наконец найдено. Спасибо!